# leadfoot vs webdriver.io - javascript client library for selenium WebDriver API

Tags: javascript, intern, webdriver-io

What is the difference between intern's leadfoot and webdriver.io? Would appreciate, if some one can list down the pros and cons of both?

Leadfoot - https://github.com/theintern/leadfoot
webdriver.io - http://webdriver.io/

Comment: I've asked the broader question, [WebdriverIO vs. Intern](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/685), on Webdriver's GitHub.